# Replace not work in iPad, how to use replace in iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jquery-events

I have used below code for replacing html, it is working in browser but not working in iPad Safari browser how to resolve this?

```
var text=$('#content_area').html();
var text2=text.replace('<span style="background-color: rgb(233, 207, 236);">proposes</span>'
, 'proposes'); 
$('#content_area').html(text2);
```

Comment: its var in js like var range='proposes'..

Comment: Do you see any error in the Javascript console of mobile Safari? You can enable it in `Settings > Safari > Developer` (or something like that).

Comment: This is the trouble when you love your code, you never see the bad times coming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're Doing It Wrong™. Don't modify raw HTML strings, modify the DOM.

```
$( '#content_area span:contains("proposes")' ).replaceWith( 'proposes' );
```

You *could* select by background color as well, but it's not as reliable. The problem is most likely that the Mobile Safari doesn't keep the color as rgb() but in hex format, so something like this might work:

```
$( '#content_area span' ).filter(function() {
    return ( $(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(233, 207, 236)' 
          || $(this).css('background-color').toLowerCase() === '#e9cfec' );
}).replaceWith( 'proposes' );
```

The best solution would be if you can add a class to the spans or otherwise reliably distinguish them so that the selector would be unambiguous.